# Show that $ \Gamma(1-z)=-\frac{1}{z-1}+\cdots $

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I am a bit confusing about this notation. How to show that ?
$$
\Gamma(1-z)=-\frac{1}{z-1}+\cdots
$$
Reference:

http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/213b_spring_05/functional_equation_by_residues.pdf

Comment: That's easy. Proving that whatever is behind the $\cdots$ has some specific form (like being a power series centered at $z = 1$ with no negative-power terms) is a bit more difficult. What exactly do you want to prove?

Comment: How to specific power series for this ? $\Gamma (1-z)=\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{-z}e^{-x}\,dx,\ \qquad \Re (z)>0\  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent was most likely that they were showing the terms of the Laurent expansion at negative powers to obtain the residues. Note that:

\begin{align}\Gamma(1-z)&=\frac{\Gamma(2-z)}{1-z}\\&=\frac{\Gamma(1)-\Gamma'(1)(z-1)+\mathcal O(z-1)^2}{1-z}\\&=\frac1{1-z}+\Gamma'(1)+\mathcal O(z-1)\end{align}

as $z\to1$.